# Laptop HDD/SSD in RAID 1 - good idea?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, backup, raid

So I am planning to get a desktop replacement primarily to be used at home (maybe 10% of usage would be portable/lugging around). M2 SSD(/s) + HDD(/s).
I want to ensure I do not lose my data if something goes south, so was thinking of RAID 1. Data is primarily media, archives, and documents, clocking in at over 300gb, edited weekly, significant changes ~monthly.

Should I bother with RAIDing SSDs or are they fairly reliable?
Overall, is RAID 1 in a laptop a good idea, or just a backup would suffice?

Comment: RAID is not a backup, it doesn't save your data from deletions, software errors, spilling coffee on your laptop etc.

Comment: @sebasth yeah, I'm aware of that and don't plan to replace regular backups with raid